# Nesting generator expressions in the argument list for a python function call

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

I like to use the following idiom for combining lists together, sometimes:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(*[[(e, n) for e in l] for n, l in (('a', [1,2]),('b',[3,4]))]))
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'b')]
```

(I know there are easier ways to get this particular result, but it comes comes in handy when you want to iterate over the elements in lists of lists of lists, or something like that.  The trouble is, when you use generator expressions, this becomes error prone.  E.g.

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(*(((e, n) for e in l) for n, l in (('a', [1,2]),('b',[3,4])))))
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'b')]
```

What's happening here is that the inner generator expressions get passed as arguments to `itertools.chain`, so at the the time they're evaluated, the outer generator expression has finished, and `n` is fixed at its final value, `'b'`. I'm wondering whether anyone has thought of ways to avoid this kind of error, beyond "don't do that."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach almost works, you just need to flatten the generators. See how the `for e in l` is moved to the very right

```
>>> list(itertools.chain((e, n) for n, l in (('a', [1,2]),('b',[3,4])) for e in l ))
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'b')]
```

Here is how to do the same thing using itertools.product

```
>>> X=itertools.chain(*(itertools.product(*i[::-1]) for i in (('a', [1,2]),('b',[3,4]))))
>>> print list(X)
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'b')]
```

or if you are allowed to switch the tuples around

```
>>> X=itertools.chain(*(itertools.product(*i) for i in (([1,2],'a'),([3,4],'b'))))
>>> print list(X)
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'b')]
```

Comment: Thanks, the product function looks like it ought to be safer and lead to clearer expressions.

Answer (score 6):

wouldn't a nested list comprehension be more appropriate?

```
>>> tt = (('a', [1,2]),('b',[3,4]))
>>> [(s, i) for i, l in tt for s in l]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'b')]
```

Comment: You can stick it all in the one list comprehension, in this case, but it's more complicated to do that in some cases.  I simplified the example for clarity.

Comment: why do stick it into a single line? why not just nested for loops? that would be both more clear and won't require any intermediate lists to be built.

Comment: but isn't question about 'generator expressions' not working ?

Comment: but to me it seems it's not a question at all. OP is quite clear why generators don't work. the only unclear thing here is why is he trying to use them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest

```
data = (('a', [1,2]), ('b', [3,4]))

result = []
for letter, numbers in data:
     for number in numbers:
         result.append((number, letter))
```

It's a lot more readable than your solution family. Fancy is not a good thing.